# Shorter time frames for candidates and cheaper membership

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Candidates don't need to have a year long membership to be searchable by employers. They typically are only available for a month for hire, so it is silly to pay for a full year. Also employeers won't want results for candidates that have already been employed.

Charge on a monthly basis and something small. That is enough to show that you are an active job seeker.

Answer (score 4):

Charging every month means *by definition* that you are forcing a scammy recurring billing scheme on your users. I am … not a fan.

It's possible we might offer a 6 month option, but nothing shorter than that.

Comment: I like the 6 month plan idea. Careers doesn't have huge value for me yet since I doubt a lot of ZA employers will sign up, however once I am in a position to relocate it will most definitely be an option, but a 1 year sign up is a bit to long. 3 or 6 months might be a better option. Also, your CV remains even after filing, so you could always just sign up again later when you are actively looking.

Comment: You're only forcing recurring billing if it takes people longer than a month to find a job through the site.

Comment: IMHO, it's only scammy if it's on an opt out basis. You can make it such that the monthly subscriber gets a renewal reminder a few days before expiry, and if the user doesn't renew by the expiry date, then the subscription simply lapses. You could give users a choice of durations: 1 month, 3 months, 6 months, 1 year, etc., then it would be up to them as to how long to subscribe for. The pricing could be done such that, on a $/month basis, it's more economical as the intervals increase. That would help offset the added expense of processing more renewals of the shorter intervals.

Comment: @Jeff - Just because you have an aversion to recurring billing doesn't mean everyone does.  I'd prefer to pay for a service while I'm using it and not pay for it when I'm not.  You may eventually end up tweaking the pricing if it prevents you from getting to the critical mass you need to be successful with this kind of service.

Answer (score 2):

> Candidates don't need to have a year long membership to be searchable by employers.

Well, that may be so in US, but in many regions of the world (such as Europe) to be looking for a job for average 2 years until you find a good match is a norm. Even if you're highly qualified.

In that situation monthly subscriptions would only be extra effort. Each month your process a payment and lose each time some fee, so 12 times a year instead of 1 or 2.

Comment: If the site doesn't deliver the goods after 2 months of serving you, then I would stop using them at that point. 

Something is wrong with either your skill-set or your career choice (market over-saturation?) if you are job searching for 2 years.

Comment: unknown - regardless of qualification, unemployment rates, and enforced workweeks (as some european countries have) can play-into this, too

Comment: It's somewhat impossible to be both "highly qualified" for a variety of opportunities (i.e. breath) and yet have the depth to be a specific match for a specific opportunity.  "Good" matches are almost always rare, everywhere, and both sides generally need to settle for "good enough" and then just try to increase your definition of "good enough" over time.

Answer (score 0):

Even at $99/year I don't see much value for anything shorter than 3 months and could probably live with 6 months.  Doing a per-month option at $10 or less per month seems like too much overhead.  If you get a new job in less than the amount of time you've paid for does it really matter?  Just mark your profile as not searchable and take yourself off the market.

I think the way to think about is really whether $99 is worth it to get a new job whether you plan to be looking for 1 month or 12 months.  If you don't find enough value in advertising yourself through SO to offset the cost, then don't play the game.  I'm sure that if there isn't enough developer demand at the price/time levels that are available, the rates/times will change to reflect a better model (or @Jeff will get of the careers business).